# HTACCESS causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

NOTE: The code is not being sanitized here for simple explanation of problem, keeping basics. My production code will sanitize the $_GET before handling.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/files/"

RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ ?cat=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ?cat=$1
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
$title = $_GET['title'];

if($cat && !$title) {
    echo 1;
} 

if($cat && $title) {
    echo 2;
}
```

If I go to my test url of: http://local.testzone.com/cat/title OR http://local.testzone.com/cat

I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

If I comment the last line in the .htaccess file:

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*) ?cat=$1
```

http://local.testzone.com/cat gives me:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /cat was not found on this server.

http://local.testzone.com/cat/title gives me:

> 2

Which is what it should do, according my my php echo of 2 if cat and title exist.

My question is - how do I modify the access file so if there is just a cat, it will echo the 1?  The only way I could do this is to manually set the first level like this:

```
RewriteRule ^cat$ ?cat=cat
```

This works, but will not work in the application I am writing.  I need to query a database based on the cat value in the URL. The cat value can dynamically change and I cannot hard code it into the htaccess file. The title is working fine but how do I get the cat portion to function?

Hope I was clear in my request, looking forward to any assistance!

Comment: Your rewrite rules cause infinite loop, apache probably breaks after 10 redirects. Try to review them, especially this one : RewriteRule ^(.*) ?cat=$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean up some of your rules, but you need to add a condition to keep your rules from looping. The rewrite enging will continually run the request URI through your rules until the URI stops changing (or you reach the internal recursion limit, thus the 500 error).

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?files/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ ?cat=$1&title=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) ?cat=$1
```